# How do I attach a process to the debugger in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I know I can start a process in code with `Process.Start()`.
Is it also possible to attach the debugger to that process?

Not from code *per se* , but just a way to do it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can [attach to a running process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228818.aspx) using `Tools | Attach to Process`.  If it's a Web Application, you can attach to it by attaching to `aspnet_wp.exe` or `w3wp.exe`.

To answer your question on how to attach to a process programmatically:

- [Attaching to a Process Using VS.NET Automation Model](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2003/02/09/2076.aspx)

Here are other Stack Overflow questions that deal with that:

- [Communicating with the Visual Studio Debugger Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201504/is-it-possible-to-communicate-with-the-visual-studio-debugger-programmatically-wh)
- [Programmatically apply breakpoints in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841782/programmatically-apply-deactivate-breakpoints-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 3):

In visual studio click Tools | Attach to process.  Then select appropriate service.

Comment: On later versions of Visual Studio it's under Debug | Attach to process (instead of under Tools menu).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in your code.

```
public static void Attach(DTE2 dte)
        {
            var processes = dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses;
            foreach (var proc in processes.Cast<EnvDTE.Process>().Where(proc => proc.Name.IndexOf("YourProcess.exe") != -1))
                proc.Attach();
        }

        internal static DTE2 GetCurrent()
        {
            var dte2 = (DTE2)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0"); // For VisualStudio 2013

            return dte2;
        }
```

Usage:

```
Attach(GetCurrent());
```

Comment: `Marshall.GetActiveObject()` is not available in .NET Core, but you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/64826127/137646 as a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in pretty much any debugger worth its salt.

Visual Studio has one that should fit your needs.

If you need a little more advanced control, try [OllyDbg](http://ollydbg.de/), which is a disassembler, so you can actually manipulate your program at the assembly level. This will give you complete control, but it might be information overload as well.

Comment: WinDbg should be used. WinDbg with SOS really trumps OllyDbg for .NET. OllyDbg has more "analysis" features but WinDbg is more appropriate here -- where the OP probably only wants to debug his own process

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2015, click 'Debug > Attach to process' in the menu. Alternatively, there is a shortcut key Ctrl+Alt+P.

Answer (score 0):

I use vs 2022 and it's under Debug | Attach to process. (ss attached)
[image]