# How to start a child process in the same Visual Studio debugging session as the parent, programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

When running a process under the debugger, I would like to start a child process in the same debugger.

Currently, I use

```
Process.Start("sample.exe");
```

I want it to be something like this:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    // start "sample.exe" in the same debugging session
else
    Process.Start("sample.exe");
```

I could pass a flag to the child process that instructs it to call `Debugger.Launch()`, but that won't catch start up errors, and it results in a debugging session where some features are not enabled (such as edit and continue, etc). It's preferable to have the debugger launch the process directly.

Comment: I suspect the title of this question is very misleading - are you trying to start this process with VS, or with a C# application that happens to be built using VS?

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The problem is that Visual Studio won't automatically attach to child processes out of the box. There are solutions for that though.

Comment: Will: neither. am trying to start a process from a application built in c# but running in debug mode in VS. So in a way both your statements is valid.

Comment: should I close/delete this question as it is dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986470/start-process-and-attach-debugger

Comment: We don't delete dupes; people search, find this one, and then are led to the answer.  Its like a signpost pointing to Winsville.

Comment: A simpler solution is to call Main in sample.exe's project.

Comment: @HenryAloni The problem is that we need multiple STA threads for 2 winform programs and c# has many values that are in static properties.

Comment: This is not a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986470/how-do-i-attach-a-process-to-the-debugger-in-visual-studio -- that question talks about attaching a debugger manually. The OP here is asking about doing so programmatically from a debuggee that's already running under the debugger.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should attach debugger to process you are starting. This could be done:

1. Manually from Visual Studio after starting "sample.exe" select it menu Debug > Attach to process..
2. Programmatically attach debugger inside "sample.exe"
3. [Attaching to a Process using VS.NET Automation Model](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2003/02/09/2076.aspx)
4. **UPDATE:** You can setup windows environment to attach debugger every time "sample.exe" starts: [Launch the Debugger Automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=VS.90).aspx) (you will need to call Debugger.Break anyway)
5. Some external tool maybe

Here is code for "sample.exe" to attach debugger:

```
if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
     Debugger.Launch();
Debugger.Break();
```

You should pass some parameter to "sample.exe" to verify if you need to attach debugger.

```
Process.Start("sample.exe", "Debug=true");
```

Comment: It launches another VS. Is it possible to have it in the same instance of VS.

Comment: Well, never thought about this. Launching another VS is a default behavior. BTW I found good walkaround for starting process in debug mode without modifying it.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky but this requires opening new VS. How can we do it in same Visual Studio instance if child process project is already existing within same solution? Thanks

Comment: If the launched program happens to be the same as the launcher, VS10 (at least) doesn't open a new instance. In that case step one is the easiest , but in choosing step two, with the program as a debug compile, obviously `"Debug=true"` isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the properties of your solution to start multiple apps.

an explanation is here [Run Multiple projects](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/20306-Running-multiple-projects-one-solution.aspx)

The MSDN article is here [MSDN Article on running multiple projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a404w14b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: This is a good solution if all processes start at the same time. However if a child process can start at some later time, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that sample.exe would be the host for code you want to debug, you can use project properties -> debug settings - choose action as an external program and provide path to sample.exe. The VS will start this executable and attach the debugger to it.

Comment: Its a programmatic start that is needed as it is part of program logic.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Debugger Team created an extension that does that automagically:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool