# Start a VB.NET Application without pressing F5

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have developed a small application in VS 2010 (Using VB.NET). My application communicates with another .exe file and shares information. I want my application to start running when the the other .exe file is started. Is this possible? I have heard about attach to process option in VS 2010, How does it work and will it suit my requirement ?

With regards,
nandgate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814361/how-can-i-start-another-process-in-debug-mode-in-visual-studio-2010 might help.

Answer (score 3):

Attach to process will only attach the debugger to an already running process - it will not run it for you.

You can start the other application at any time by going to the `bin` directory it is in and running it.

If you want to automate this, you can look at the `Build events` tab of the project properties and set a post build event pointing to the other executable. This will start the other executable when a build has finished.