# Visual Studio 2012 - Stepping through multiple projects?

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, projects

I have 2 projects under the same solution in visual studio 2012.

The 1st is a WPF project, the 2nd is an ASP project.

The WPF calls an asp page via the webbrowser control. Is there anyway I can step into the code behind of the ASP page even though it is not my start up project?

Comment: [Possible dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986470/how-do-i-attach-a-process-to-the-debugger-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 2):

You can set both the WPF project *and* the ASP project to be loaded when you debug.  In solution explorer, right click the solution node and select *Properties*.  Ensure *Common Properties\Startup project* is selected in left tree.  Click the *Multiple startup projects* radio button then in the list set the project you want to start when you debug (F5) to *Start*.

Now when you press F5 to debug both projects will be started and you can put breakpoints in both.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the debbuger to corresponding ISS process. In Visual Studio:

Click "Debug" from the menu bar
Click "Attach to Process"
Check the "Show processes from all users" checkbox in the bottom left corner
Select aspnet_wp.exe (or w3wp.exe  depending on your ISS version) from the process list
Click "Attach"