# Is there a substitue for System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject() in .NET Core?

Tags: .net, com

The method `GetActiveObject()` is available in `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal` in .NET Framework, but not in .NET Core (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58010881/180275).

Is there a way around if I want to use .NET Core (from PowerShell 7)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That specific API is gone, but you can easily P/Invoke [`GetActiveObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-getactiveobject) to get that information.

Comment: tell us how please?

Comment: The function takes one argument, the `progId` and returns the COM object. The other answer even gives you the straight up code to use it. What is confusing you?

Answer (score 9):

Here is an equivalent implementation that works for .NET core 3.1+ on Windows (and .NET framework):

```
public static object GetActiveObject(string progId, bool throwOnError = false)
{
    if (progId == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(progId));

    var hr = CLSIDFromProgIDEx(progId, out var clsid);
    if (hr < 0)
    {
        if (throwOnError)
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        return null;
    }

    hr = GetActiveObject(clsid, IntPtr.Zero, out var obj);
    if (hr < 0)
    {
        if (throwOnError)
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        return null;
    }
    return obj;
}

[DllImport("ole32")]
private static extern int CLSIDFromProgIDEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszProgID, out Guid lpclsid);

[DllImport("oleaut32")]
private static extern int GetActiveObject([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rclsid, IntPtr pvReserved, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppunk);
```

I'm not a Powershell expert, but I think you can port that to Powershell or use a bit of C# directly in Powershell.

Comment: Awesome thanks for this. To get to this in powershell you can use Add-Type. Add the above script into a $methodDef variable and do something better than this 
```$blah = add-type -MemberDefinition $methodDef -Name "Blah" -Namespace "Blah" -PassThru``` then use it as ```$dte = $blah::GetActiveObject('VisualStudio.DTE.16.0')```
[More information on Add-Type here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-interact-with-the-windows-api-part-1/)