# How to create a new Application Interface without running a new instance of the Application process

Tags: c#, com

I am using COM Interface of an Application to automate my works:

`HYSYS.Application HyApp = new HYSYS.Application();`

The above code creates a new Instance of the application and a new COM Interface for it.
I can check if the Application is already running by its process name like this:

```
List<Process> procs = new List<Process>();
procs.AddRange(Process.GetProcessesByName("AspenHysys"));
```

But don't know how to create the COM Interface for the running process.

Comment: I don't think its possible. If just creation of object invokes creation of process - you can't skip that part and "attach" it. Kill process and start over.

Comment: I think about something similar to 
```oExcelApp =  (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")```
But it doesn't work

Comment: You're not supposed to do that by yourself. The HYSYS.Application designer choose to keep an instance per client or a shared one, and they also choose to expose running instances or not. ie: e call such as GetActiveObject works if they choose to support it. You should contact them for what they exactly support.

Comment: I cant see `GetAciveObject` method 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal?view=net-7.0
Is it removed?

Comment: In .NET Core yes (you can find an equivalent here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64823199/is-there-a-substitue-for-system-runtime-interopservices-marshal-getactiveobject) but that doesn't change anything to the question.

Comment: The main problem is running a new Instance every time waste my time during testing and development, maybe I should find a way to serialize the COM Interface.