# VS2010 - Break on events without intellitrace

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, events, event-handling, breakpoints

I have VS2010 professional and Im working with a large code base that Im unfamiliar with. I want to know what code gets executed when a certain event occurs (namely, when I click a specific button). I know this could easily be done with Intellitrace, but that requires an Ultimate subscription (which is outrageously expensive). Is there any other way I can do this? Ideally without installing anything new (even if its free), but thats not a deal breaker.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the event handler.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes... that would be the obvious solution. The point is that I have no idea where the event handler is. Thats why Im looking for it... Moreover I have a hunch that the top level event handler is actually in some other code I dont have access to, so Im not sure how its done on my level

Comment: Just double-click the button in the designer and the IDE takes you right to it.  That was too obvious of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what .NET code is executed with [Runtime Flow](http://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) (developed by me, 30-day trial).

Comment: I actually have been trying to use that, but I need to get installations pre-approved, so could take a while :(