# C# - How would I go to first line of executed code after an event without setting breakpoints

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, web

Is there a way to force VS to show every line of code that is executed after a click event? I am not sure where the first line of code is that will be executed so placing a specific breakpoint will not help. I am using c# with asp.net if that matters.

Comment: put a break point at an earlier point then move F10 step by step

Comment: client or server side?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978364/debugging-all-events-in-visual-studio-2010-without-setting-break-points).

Comment: there is a user click so I don't think I can use a breakpoint that is to early

Answer (score 1):

you can put a breakpoint at the first known line (that you can pragmatically state), when it stops, check the stacktrace, keep clicking on the previous statements to check the order. It may be that some of these statemnts are CLR and you may not have source code, but that tells you atleast what the statement is doing.

[image: call Stack]

Comment: Where is previous statement located on VS2013

Comment: please see edit, by default vs wont show external code